# Entity Framework - Linking to the Same Table

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am trying to model the following classes using *Entity Framework* (version 6.1.3)

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public Guid BlogPostId { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    // Navigation
    public virtual ICollection<BlogPostBlogPostLink> RelatedBlogs { get; set;
}

public class BlogPostBlogPostLink
{
    public Guid BlogPostId { get; set; }
    public Guid LinkedBlogPostId { get; set; }
    public int Relevance { get; set; }

    // Navigation
    public virtual BlogPost BlogPost { get; set; }
    public virtual BlogPost LinkedBlogPost { get; set; }
}
```

The idea being that the BlogPost author can potentially link to other BlogPosts and assign and sort them in order of relevance.

The problem I have is mapping these in Entity Framework.  This is what I have tried...

```
public class BlogPostMap 
    : EntityTypeConfiguration<BlogPost>
{
    public BlogPostMap()
    {
        ToTable("blog_BlogPost");

        // Primary Key
        HasKey(bp => bp.BlogPostId);

        HasMany(bp => bp.RelatedBlogs)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("BlogPostId");
                m.MapRightKey("LinkedBlogPostId");
                m.ToTable("blog_BlogPostBlogPostLink");
            });
    }
}

public class BlogPostBlogPostLinkMap 
    : EntityTypeConfiguration<BlogPostBlogPostLink>
{
    public BlogPostBlogPostLinkMap()
    {
        ToTable("blog_BlogPostBlogPostLink");

        // Composite Primary Key
        HasKey(bpl => new { bpl.BlogPostId, bpl.LinkedBlogPostId });

        // Properties
        Property(bp => bp.BlogPostId)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("BlogPostId");

        Property(bpl => bpl.LinkedBlogPostId)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("LinkedBlogPostId");

        // Relationships
        HasRequired(bpl => bpl.BlogPost);
        HasRequired(bpl => bpl.LinkedBlogPost);
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

*_The specified association foreign key columns 'LinkedBlogPostId' are invalid. The number of columns specified must match the number of primary key columns._*

Any advice/direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: based on the entity's strcture `HasMany(bp => bp.RelatedBlogs).WithMany()` should be   `HasMany(bp => bp.RelatedBlogs)
            .WithOne()`

Comment: This is tagged EF 6, not core.

Comment: I don't think I have the .WithOne() option available to me - could you perhaps expand a little further please?

Comment: Besides the incorrect configuration, you can't map two reference navigation properties `BlogPost` and `LinkedBlogPost` to a single collection navigation property `RelatedBlogs`. You need to decide first which property maps to the existing collection and if you will introduce second collection or not.

Comment: Hi Ivan, so are you saying I can only map one way through this structure?